# What will be the effect of placing a light source very close to a photodiode?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, spectroscopy, electronics

What will be the effect of placing a photodiode really close to a laser source and what should be the appropriate distance between a light source and photodiode to get maximum output current?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the laser is emitting a wavelength that the photodiode is sensitive to. If the laser has too much power, you would burn out the semiconductor. Since a laser is a collimate light source, the power lose is minimal for any distance unless there is fog.

What type of photodiode do you have? Some are like transistors with low gain and others are FETs or even Darlington transistors (very high gain). What is the purpose of the light signal? Is it just an indicator, or does the signal depend on the intensity?

Comment: [Lasers are not collimated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_divergence) light sources, but they can easily be made collimated using lenses.

Comment: We are using FDS025 by Thorlabs and the purpose of the light is to reflect some changes which we are measuring in the experiment so the intensity very well defines our signal.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the photodiode's ball lens is arranged to focus a collimated beam onto the diode so ideally you would want to create such a beam with a diameter less than the diameter of the lens to avoid large reflections and poor focus as the rays move off the optical axis. As long as the beam is arranged like that the distance shouldn't matter, but it becomes harder to accomplish as the distance increases since it will not be perfectly collimated.